# Custom segmentation based on custom user fields

Tags: experience-analytics, custom-field, indexing

I am running **Sitecore 8.1 rev 3**.

I have indexed the values I want to segment against in an index, but those are associated to each user profile - not against a Contact. I can, however, easily associate each user with a Contact.

Do I have to build the index from each Contact instead, and then use this index in a custom `Rule Condition` class, like depicted in this [this blog post](https://jonathanrobbins.co.uk/2017/01/03/index-custom-xdb-facets-to-segment-contacts-in-sitecore-list-manager/)?

Answer (score 3):

Segmentation rules ONLY work against xDB contacts. If you have any properties in the user profile (aka asp.net members profile properties), then this will never work. You need to push those properties to a custom xDB facet.

Segmentation rules are just predicates that are added the xDB search query.

Comment: So, how do I create a custom xDB facet?

Comment: I think you are going to need to move to 8.2. That was the 1st version with real xDB and mongo. https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/82/sitecore-experience-platform/en/create-a-custom-contact-facet.html. But honestly you really need to get into 9.x